# Spark dataframe fails to collect and aggregate 2000 columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe of time series data with a column for each time point. This was done so aggregations at different times of the day would be fast. However, if I try and and aggregate rows for an entire day (2880 columns) I get an error like below:

```
`"ERROR scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 8.0 failed 4 times; aborting job"
```

with a long stack trace starting with the line:-

```
"Spark Exception: Job aborted due to stage failure".`
```

Example code:

```
df =  spark.sql("select * from my_table")

epochs = list(range(0,2880))

row = df.agg({ str(e): "mean" for e in epochs}).first()
```

I don't get this error if I only aggregate on 960 columns.
I also don't get any error if I just call collect().
I've tried raising the spark.driver.maxResultSize & spark.driver.memory settings

Often spark will give recommendation on what config to change if it is failing for memory issues but it doesn't say anything in this case.

Are there any config settings I could change or could I structure my dataframe differently?

Comment: How many rows are you aggregating each time?

Comment: Eventually 6000 but this happens now with 1 row

Comment: Could you post a repro? Also showing the code that you are using will help us understand what may be going wrong

Comment: Hi Selnay, I've added some example code to the original post